# Differences in UV/vis absorbance spectrum of tap water and distilled water

Tags: analytical-chemistry

In my lecture, I was told that the absorbance of a substance can be measured by a colorimeter. By connecting the device to a computer, a graph showing the wavelengths and absorbance values can be shown. I suppose the graph is called a "spectrum".

My lecturer used deionized water in the experiment for calibration.

Then I wonder, if there are any differences (even subtle ones) in the spectrum of tap water and distilled/deionized water?

I understand that the result does not cause major effects to the measurement. What are those effects?

Comment: There is possible to not selectively determine nitrate context in water by water UV absorption near 220 nm.

Comment: It depends on the tap water. For example, if there are minerals that start to precipitate during water treatment, it might increase turbidity and scattering. A community near me has *very* high concentrations of Fe and Mn in the tap water, giving it a muddy brown-black appearance. (It's supposedly safe for drinking, but not appealing.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a broad question, since it can be rephrased as "what compounds might be found in tap water that can be detected by direct measurement by UV spectroscopy".

Obviously one answer cannot address all sources of tap water, and the question does not specify a level of purity. At least one recent study ([1](https://doi.org/10.1038/s41598-021-83322-w)) suggests UV measurement as a method of detecting some  contaminants of concern:

> Contaminants in water were studied using ultraviolet absorption with light emitting diode and
> deuterium lamp sources, and a thresholding detector. The absorption spectra of potassium hydrogen
> pthalate, clothianidin, tryptophan, thiamethoxam, uric acid and metaldehyde were obtained in the
> range 200–360 nm. Only metaldehyde was not suitable for detection in this range. For the other
> contaminants, and mixtures of pairs of compounds, the transmitted signal could be approximately
> described with a simple spectral model of the source–absorption–detector system. Combined
> measurements at two wavelengths could allow relative concentrations in certain mixtures to be
> determined, and real-time absorption measurements were demonstrated in a flume.

Regarding what effects these particular compounds had on the UV spectrum, obviously detection requires that there is a difference between pure (e.g. distilled) water and the contaminated one. From the results:

> UV absorption spectra were measured for a range of contaminants in water (concentration 10 mg/L, optical path 10 mm in silica glass cuvettes). These are shown in Fig. 1 for six substances relevant to water quality. All are transparent in the soft UV and visible range. Clothianidin and thiamethoxam are neonicotinoid pesticides. Each has a pair of broad absorption features below 280 nm. Tryptophan is an amino acid whose UV fluorescence is similar to that of organic matter such as sewage and farm slurry 31 . This shows a broad peak around 280 nm (absorption here is also associated with fluorescence at 340 nm) and a sharper peak at 220 nm. Potassium hydrogen pthalate (KHP) is used as a calibration standard for TOC measurements, and shows a steady increase of UV absorption below 250 nm. Metaldehyde, a pesticide for slugs and snails, absorbs rather weakly across the UV range studied and we found that it was not possible to reliably detect this compound with UV LEDs of wavelength 250 nm and above. Uric acid is present in untreated sewage but is not normally found in unpolluted waters 32 . It shows broad peaks at around 235 and 290 nm, and a peak or edge at 200 nm.

1. Spangenberg, M., Bryant, J.I., Gibson, S.J. et al. Ultraviolet absorption of contaminants in water. *Sci Rep* **11**, 3682 (2021). https://doi.org/10.1038/s41598-021-83322-w